# Retrieving flow from org in VSCode throws "UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL"

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api

Here is my flow version - 55
Here is the org version - 55
Here is the sourceApiVersion on the sfdx.project.json file - 55
sfdx cli version - 7.155.1

This works perfectly fine when retrieving from one of my other sandboxes.

Please advise on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you setting the version to `55.0`?

Comment: @PhilW setting it where?

Comment: In the `sfdx-project.json`.

Comment: Yes I did set it there.

Comment: And you set it including the `.0`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the part of the `sfdx-project.json` and the exact and full error message.

Comment: Not sure what happened during the weekend, today I tested retrieving source from the org and it worked. Have no clue what I was doing wrong on Friday.